# Do companies usualy change PCB layout if they create different versions for different markets?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-assembly

I was wondering what's common practice.

If a company like Samsung for instance creates a phone for the international market (SM-G975F) and the Korean market (SM-G975N), and the Korean phone has some extra features (extra chips), will the company change the PCB layout?

If the pads where the chips should be are unavailable, does this mean that signals are connected on the board? And if a user knows which chip to add where, would it be possible (i.e. will the signals from it pass to the desired places)?

I mean, how do you guys do that, do you change PCB layout, maybe cut traces and leave empty pads there for decoration and to confuse Chinese cloners?

I just need some common advice, because if this is common practice, then I assume Samsung would do the same.

In my particular case (SM-G975N has chips (RTC6213N - 1204-003661 in the service manual - should be in the U11003 place) that the SM-G975F does not have, and I would like to add them, but because I don't know how to solder myself I have to know exacly what needs to go where and if this is possible before I ask someone to solder that for me.

Comment: It depends. It might not be the same PCB since it is a different product version for a different market with other differences as well. And even if you have places for chips, why would you add them, and why would the phone know you added some chip somewhere, if the software does not use that chip?

Comment: What are you going to do if the firmware is not expecting the chip that you are going to add in?

Comment: @Justme I will add them, because the phone lacks the feature (FM Radio) (that in my opinion should be standard everywhere) I need, and I will modify the firmware, this is android so, just need to recompile the kernel, chip uses i2c (like other things on the phone, so hardware to read i2c is there), kernel is open source by samsung

Comment: Please understand that modifying an expensive phone may end up badly. It is possible that you damage the hardware when adding the chips and other required components. Where would you even get those chips? It is possible that the chips are left out because the feature does not work in that hardware. You may also accidentally brick it by flashing an incompatible kernel or bootloader or whatever.

Comment: "FM Radio ... should be standard" Why? I've had phones with that feature and never used it. Why make phones more expensive for features that aren't wanted?

Comment: @LaCalienta In the particular case of a mobile phone, it is possible that the ICs that deal with the phone radio signals are also different. It would probably be cheaper to buy the model of phone that you think you want and see if it works where you are than to buy some chips which may or may not work and get them soldered in, which may or may not break the original phone.

Comment: Depends, some companies will bend over backwards to eliminate SKU's for inventory, Some want to reduce costs, depends on the company.

Comment: @Finbarr not a scope of this post, but Samsung aint cheaper for you if you are missing a feature, they just pocket the difference (and they create phones with FM Radio in korea (at least S10 had it)

Also maybe you don't use FM Radio, what about SDCard or headphone jack, this is maybe easier to understand for normal people if its missing

Companies (at least in phone sectors) are stagnating with phone inovation nowadays, so the only inovations they make now is how to get more profit with less parts

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the volume and what will make the biggest savings.

If I am playing in a small market then I probably design the PCB to be able to get as many BOM variants as I can out of the one board, because the cost of a little extra area or weight is less then the cost of my amortised engineering time doing two versions.

If I am realistically expecting to sell a few million of each version then I am cooking two boards because it will be worth my time.

Comment: ah, I see, but do you also put pads there

Like in Samsungs case, pads are there for chips, so I guess connections are there as well

Like do companies put pads for decoration only?

Comment: If the footprints are there the connections will be, but note that quite often a designer will change some parts that are there to save a little money on the version that is not full featured.

Comment: What do you mean the designer will change some parts to save money? Will it put a resistor instead of diode on the empty spot?

Here is a practical example: https://www.mediafire.com/file/oamcped1jb82gi8/shema.pdf/file

if you check page 13 you will see for FM Radio KOR Only, EUR open

Now what does this mean, that I can put chips where they belong and they will be electricly connected to peripherals? (software doesnt matter here, I will deal with this later when electricly everything is connected)

There are test points, but I have no idea what device to use to test that

Comment: Eh, it means it might be as simple as adding the extra parts and patching the software, but that is not a given and all you can really do is try. If for example there is another version of the processor that lacks something like an I2S interface but is otherwise identical, I could see using that on the EU product if the only thing that needed that interface was the radio, and it saved me a few cents (or a few mW). If a power rail is only critical on the KOR version a filter inductor might be replaced with a 0R resistor, that sort of thing.